# access iphone user settings from javascript

Tags: javascript, iphone, ios4

is there a way to access an app's iphone user default settings from javascript?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create a JS function to call from the Objective-C side that copies settings over, but there's no way for the JS layer to directly access the settings in your app.